# What elements in the movie Steel are from the comics and were any later added to the comics?

Tags: dc

*Steel* is a movie. Supposedly, it's based on the DC Comics character John Henry Irons/Steel. Was anything from the comics used in the film besides having a character named John Henry Irons who puts on a suit of armor? Was anything from the film later brought into the comics? These elements include:

- A wheelchair bound, techy sidekick (in the vein of Oracle) nicknamed Sparky who Steel has will they-won't they chemistry with
- A mentor named Uncle Joe who assists Steel in his superhero-ing
- A grandmother who owns a soufflé restaurant
- A nemesis who worked with him in the past but stole the weapons that he designed; his villainous plan is to sell illegal weapons via arcades and the internet
- A younger family member (nephew?) named Martin
- A voice changer that can make Steel sound like Arnold Schwarzenegger

Additionally, I would appreciate if Shaquille O'Neal was at all referenced in Steel comics after the movie came out and bombed.

Comment: “Steel is a movie” — I think that was the review quote they picked for the DVD cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question says, what was from the comics, and what was later added to the comics. Here are things taken from / inspired by the comics

- The Oracle like techie in the movie is directly inspired from Oracle from the comics. - [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120207/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)
- While the characters are different than they are in the movie, part of Steel's storylines are his extended family, including grandparents and nephews. - [Dc Fandom](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/John_Henry_Irons_(New_Earth))
- Colonel Weston was his mentor and colleague at a weapons tech facility, until John learned he was selling weapons to criminals and he became a recurring villain. - [Colonel Thomas Weston](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/colonel-thomas-weston/4005-108968/)
- I can't find if he disguises his voice, but he is described as having a voice like "Darth Vader" [tvtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/Steel)

The only reference I can find to Shaquille O'Neal being included in DC properties as himself is in Static Shock. [Shaquille O'Neal](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Shaquille_O%27Neal)

All references to Superman were removed, supposedly this movie was meant to be a tie-in to another Superman movie they were making, which got dropped, so it was made into a solo film with no greater DC universe connection. Hence that this movie is loosely based on the comic book character.

**I cannot find anything that might have been in the movie that was later incorporated into the comics.**